# Execute a function at specific times

Tags: python-3.x

I want to execute a function at the start of every minute. The following code runs the function every minute but not necessarily at the start:

```
while True:
    func()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Is there any way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these packages that provide what you're looking for:

- https://github.com/dbader/schedule
- https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I tried `schedule` as it seems to be the easier of the two to use. But the command `schedule.every().minute.do(job)` does not schedule the job for the start of a minute. It runs the job every minute from the time of submission.

Comment: I think APScheduler would do it at the start of the minute. The other library I guess mislead me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to do it:

```
while True:
    func()
    time.sleep(60 - datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S'))
```